# ¿Identificar coeficientes de polinomios en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero obtener los coeficioentes de un polinomio y guardarlos en un arreglo, por ejemplo:

23x³+5x²+10x+5
arr[0]=23
arr[1]=5
arr[2]=10
arr[3]=5

se como evaluar las dunciones, pero en este caso solo quiero obtener los coeficientes, en python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a suponer que la entrada del problema es una cadena de caracteres que representa un polinomio de grado arbitrario (máximo 9), como la siguiente:

```
entrada = "23x³+5x²+10x+5"
```

El problema de detectar los coeficientes se puede atacar usando una expresión regular que busque dígitos seguidos opcionalmente de una `x` que vaya seguida opcionalmente de un carácter "exponente" unicode. La siguiente expresión regular hace esto, aunque se complica más de la cuenta por querer tratar también con los casos en los que no se escriba el coeficiente o el exponente, por ser 1:

```
regexp = r"(-?\d*)(x?)([¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]*)"
```

y de paso captura en diferentes grupos de captura los dígitos que aparecen antes de la `x`(y un opcional `-` por si el coeficiente es negativo), la propia `x` (que en realidad es opcional para que así funcione también con el término independiente) y los dígitos Unicode del exponente. Los dígitos delante de la x son opcionales así como los dígitos del exponente, pues pueden no aparecer como en `"x+1"`.

Tras aplicar esa expresión regular, iteramos por los grupos resultantes para guardar en un diccionario lo que encontremos. La clave del diccionario será el exponente y el valor será el coeficiente correspondiente. Hay que detectar y tratar de forma especial algunos casos:

- Si no aparece la x ni tampoco el coeficiente, ese caso nos lo saltamos
- Si no aparece el coeficiente pero sí la x, el coeficiente es "1"
- Si aparece la x y el "coeficiente" es simplemente un "-", el coeficiente es "-1".
- Si aparece la x pero no el exponente, el exponente es "1"
- Si aparece el coeficiente pero no la x, es el término independiente

Estos casos especiales ensucian un poco el código, que quedaría así:

```
c = {}
for coef, x, exp in re.findall(regexp, entrada):
  if not coef and not x:
    continue
  if x and not coef:
    coef = '1'
  if x and coef == "-":
    coef = '-1'
  if x and not exp:
    exp = '1'
  if coef and not x:
    exp = '0'
  exp = ord(exp) & 0x000F
  c[exp] = float(coef)
```

La línea `exp = ord(exp) & 0x000F` es un "truco sucio". Ocurre que los caracteres Unicode de los exponentes, al igual que los códigos ASCII de los dígitos, están ordenados de tal forma que su última cifra hexadecimal coincide con el número que representan. Por ejemplo, el código Unicode del ² es el 0x00B2, el del ³ es 0x00B3, el del ⁴ es 0x2074, etc, como se puede [ver aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block)

Aprovechándome de ese hecho, mediante un `&` lógico pongo a 0 todos los bits del código excepto los 4 últimos, y eso me da por tanto la cifra que representan.

El resultado es este diccionario:

```
{0: 5.0, 1: 10.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 23.0}
```

Ya solo queda convertir ese diccionario en una lista de modo que el índice sea el exponente y el valor sea el coeficiente. Para que la cosa sea lo suficientemente general, primero miramos cuál es la mayor de las claves (en este caso 3), pues eso nos da el grado del polinomio y por tanto el tamaño necesario de la lista resultante. El resto es solo ir rellenando:

```
grado = max(c)
coeficientes = [0.0] * (grado+1)
for g, v in c.items():
  coeficientes[g] = v
```

El resultado en este caso es:

```
[5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 23.0]
```

En la pregunta el usuario pide el orden contrario, supongo que por error, ya que lo lógico es que el índice `[i]` de esta lista nos dé el coeficiente de la potencia `i`-ésima de `x`. En todo caso, si realmente lo necesita al revés, basta que haga al final un `coeficientes.reverse()`

Juntemos todo lo anterior en una función:

```
import re

def coefs(entrada):
  regexp = r"(-?\d*)(x?)([¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]*)"
  c = {}
  for coef, x, exp in re.findall(regexp, entrada):
    if not coef and not x:
      continue
    if x and not coef:
      coef = '1'
    if x and coef == "-":
      coef = "-1"
    if x and not exp:
      exp = '1'
    if coef and not x:
      exp = '0'
    exp = ord(exp) & 0x000F
    c[exp] = float(coef)
  grado = max(c)
  coeficientes = [0.0] * (grado+1)
  for g, v in c.items():
    coeficientes[g] = v
  return coeficientes
```

**Nota** El algoritmo funciona también si los términos están desordenados, si falta alguno (el coeficiente correspondiente saldrá cero) o si hay espacios entre coeficientes. No funciona en cambio si hay un coeficiente negativo con un espacio entre el signo menos y el número.

Ejemplos de entradas y sus correspondientes salidas:

```
>>> coefs("25x²")
[0.0, 0.0, 25.0]

>>> coefs("25x⁵-x+3")
[3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0]

>>> coefs("x-23")
[-23.0, 1.0]

>>> coefs("x²-x+1")
[1.0, -1.0, 1.0]
```

He probado más, y ha funcionado, pero es posible que se me haya escapado algún otro "caso especial". Naturalmente no hace operaciones simbólicas, por lo que no funcionará tampoco con un polinomio como `"x+x"` (no suma las x).

## Actualización

Si en vez de exponentes unicode los exponentes vienen en la forma `x**N` o `x^N`, la expresión regular se complica un poco (para admitir ambas variantes) y sería:

```
regexp = r"(-?\d*)(x?)(?:(?:\^|\*\*)(\d))?"
```

Es decir, la función sería la siguiente:

```
import re

def coefs(entrada):
  regexp = r"(-?\d*)(x?)(?:(?:\^|\*\*)(\d))?"
  c = {}
  for coef, x, exp in re.findall(regexp, entrada):
    # print(coef, x, exp)
    if not coef and not x:
      continue
    if x and not coef:
      coef = '1'
    if x and coef == "-":
      coef = "-1"
    if x and not exp:
      exp = '1'
    if coef and not x:
      exp = '0'
    exp = ord(exp) & 0x000F
    c[exp] = float(coef)
  grado = max(c)
  coeficientes = [0.0] * (grado+1)
  for g, v in c.items():
    coeficientes[g] = v
  return coeficientes
```

Probando algunos ejemplos parece funcionar bien:

```
ejemplos = ["x**2-x+1", "x^2-x+1", "25x^2", "25x**2", "5x^5-x**2+3"]
for e in ejemplos:
  print(e, "\n ", coefs(e))
```

---

```
x**2-x+1 
  [1.0, -1.0, 1.0]
x^2-x+1 
  [1.0, -1.0, 1.0]
25x^2 
  [0.0, 0.0, 25.0]
25x**2 
  [0.0, 0.0, 25.0]
5x^5-x**2+3 
  [3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: como puedo cambiar los exponentes "¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹" para que los identifique ingresando "**2,**3,**4,**5..."  o  "^2,^3,^4..."

Comment: @EdgarDiaz He actualizado la respuesta para este caso